# .htaccess - ErrorDocument vs RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, http-status-code-404

I want requests for missing files and invalid directories to redirect to a custom 404 error page.  I believe this can be accomplished using 2 methods.

```
# redirect invalid requests and missing files to the not-found page  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/not-found.html [L]
# same idea but using error document  
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.html
```

Is one option better than the other?  When would I want to use one vs the other?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The rewrite rule will not return the proper status code. Meaning that a browser will see your custom error page but the response code will still be **200**, and the browser (or whatever client is talking to the server) will think that the specific bad request is actually a good request.

The `ErrorDocument` statement will show the custom error page but will also return a **404** response code, letting the browser (or whatever client) know that what it requested was not found on the server.

Note that mod_rewrite has an `R` flag that you can give a response code to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /not-found.html [L,R=404]
```

This will return a **404** response code but *it will not display* the `/not-found.html` page. It *will* display the custom error document if you use the `ErrorDocument` statement:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.html
```

The rewrite rule will force a 404, its target is essentially ignored, then the `ErrorDocument` makes sure the custom error page is served up as well as the proper **404** response.

So you want `ErrorDocument`, pretty much always. The other thing to note is that mod_rewrite is in a different place in the URI to File mapping pipeline than `ErrorDocument`. If you're relying on mod_rewrite to determine what should be 404 and what shouldn't, it's likely to be affected by other modules that may come after (like mod_proxy, for example).

---

To be clear, the `ErrorDocument` is used *after* the URL-to-file mapping pipeline concludes with a "resource not found" (i.e. a **404**), then the custom error document statement, `ErrorDoucment 404`, serves up a custom error page instead of the default one. When you use mod_rewrite like you do in your question, it completely circumvents the natural way the pipeline arrives at a **404**.

Comment: Saved me a lot of time! @Jon hats off to you!

Comment: it's look like you know much about apache.. maybe you can help this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415809/how-can-i-add-errordocument-to-this-htaccess

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work on *Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) / Debian 4.9.135-1 (2018-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux*. Apache's default error page is generated instead.