# mod_rewrite and RewriteRule blockade me from add error page

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, error-handling, custom-error-pages

i have this `.htaccess` file, but i need to want to have a 404 error page. but when i add ErrorDocument to it i do nothing. if i write `localhost:8888/home/somepage-there-not-exist`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

> it's located in the **root** same with the **app** and **public** folder

Ind the **public** folder there are this too:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]   
</IfModule>
```

---

I know the code coveret /something to files request, but when the file not exit it should get a 404 error.

It's from **laravel's** root `.htaccess` after some i like some part of the framework, but i wanna make a code block there only is there to make the website secure, and not a framework *(don't wanna invent the wheel again)*. But i still need it to understand urls that way because it make it SEO and open so there no rules are for the URL

So i have student laravel's code and figure out how it works, but this part about 404, 403 and so on.. is so complicated in laravel's and cross so maney files that you don't have a chance to understand the code and find out how laravel know when it's a 404 error.

---

**UPDATE**
I have found this [ErrorDocument-VS-RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792356/htaccess-errordocument-vs-rewriterule) 
after what i see i can use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/errors.php
```

thats kinda works, but not 100%. the ErrorDocument don't work when you are 2 steps in example: `localhost/step1/step2` and it also broke it so when the site exist it still show the error page. i have try to set the code over and under the `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`

*Yes this project is maybe stupid but i do it for lerning*

Comment: Put the complete content of the htaccess file in the question

Comment: it is the full code of my htaccess

Comment: I don't see the `ErrorDocument` there...

Comment: i try to put the `ErrorDocument` in it, and that dosen't help, thats why i ask

Comment: Do you know what the current part of the `rewrite` does? It makes no much sense to use both together

Comment: but how to check for 404 error then?

Comment: you didn't answer my question

Comment: well i don't know so much about it, i'm new to apache

Comment: Why do you even use this code if you don't understand what it does?

Comment: because i need the function of it, what i 100% do, i dont know

Comment: what is "the function of it" that you need?

Comment: So a "folder" like `localhost/home` ask for the file `home.php` but when you type `localhost/users/profile` it should ask for a file in the folder users after profile.php